# How to Enable/Disable a group of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

My spec calls for a drop down OR two calender boxes along side a radio button group to control which is active, so I made this user control:

```
<asp:RadioButton 
    GroupName="group1" 
    ID="DateMacroRadioButton" 
    runat="server" 
    Checked="true" />
<uc:DateMacroSelector ID="DateMacroSelector1" runat="server" />
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="group1" 
    ID="CustomDateRadioButton" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" Text="" />
<uc:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" />
to
<uc:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" />
```

[image]

I'd like enable/disable child controls using groups:

```
<asp:RadioButton 
    GroupName="group1" 
    ID="DateMacroRadioButton" 
    runat="server"  
    Checked="true" />
<uc:EnableGroup ID="EnableGroup1" runat="server"
   CheckBoxId="DateMacroRadioButton">
   <uc:DateMacroSelector ID="DateMacroSelector1" runat="server" />
</uc:EnableGroup>
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="group1" 
    ID="CustomDateRadioButton" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" Text="" />
<uc:EnableGroup ID="EnableGroup12 runat="server" 
    CheckBoxId="CustomDateRadioButton">
   <uc:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" />
   to
   <uc:DateSelector ID="DateSelector1" runat="server" />
</uc:EnableGroup>
```

How might I go about designing the user control that works this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom control, something like this ought to work (getting the "parsechildren" settings to make it work in the designer is always annoying but I think this is right):

```
[ParseChildren(typeof(WebControl), ChildrenAsProperties = true, 
    DefaultProperty = "ChildControls"), NonVisualControl]
public class EnableGroup: Control
{
        public EnableGroup() {
             ChildControls = new Collection<WebControl>();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (WebControl ctl in Controls) {
                ctl.Enabled = this.Enabled;
            }
            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        public Collection<WebControl> ChildControls
        {
            get; 
            protected set;
        } 
}
```

But honestly, it might be just as easy to simply write an extension method or something, e.g.

```
public static SetChildEnabled(this WebControl parent) {
    foreach (WebControl ctl in parent.Controls) {
         ctl.Enabled = parent.Enabled;
    }
}
```

Then just use any old control to wrap your groups...

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="Group1">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

and call that code on prerender:

```
Group1.SetChildEnabled()
```

You could make either work recursively pretty easily to handle deeper nested children if desired.

Come to think of it, you could probably just create a control that extends `PlaceHolder` and skip the hard part above... if you want to be able to control what object types are allowed in your container, that's how you do it, but may be overkill.

Comment: this is a nice answer - thanks - my thinking now is that i can iterate on the Controls collection and reflect for a bool property named Enabled, recursively

Comment: do you happen to know how I can make your code support the scenario of child controls that are UserControls? (talking about doing it the first way - making my own server control) - i get the error that all item types must be WebControl... just curious - i'll try the derived from placeholder way now...

Comment: OK i got it - changed web control to template control and use "is" to find out if its a type i can enable/disable.. thanks! i'll mark this answered.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd comment - I mistakenly thought that UserControl  subclassed WebControl, apparently it does not. THe only common ancestor for UserControl and WebControl seems to be Control. So your solution seems fine if you only need usercontrols in there, but if you wanted to be able to put anything then you could just use Control.